# How do I force a user to change a password at the first time login using ssh?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, login, pam

I'm trying to force a newly created user to change a password at the first time login using ssh. For security reasons I want to give him a secure password until he logs in for the first time. I did the following so far:

```
useradd -s /bin/bash -m -d /home/foo foo
passwd foo
```

Doing `chage -d 0 foo` only gives me the the error `Your account has expired; please contact your system administrator` on ssh login.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

change the age of password to 0 day

syntax `chage -d 0 {user-name}`

In this case

`chage -d0 foo`

This works for me over ssh also

Answer (score 16):

Depending on the version passwd you can try

- `passwd -f`: Forces the user to change  password  at  the next  login  by  expiring  the  password for name.
- `passwd -e` or `passwd --expire`: Immediately expire an account's password. This in effect can force a user to change his/her password at the user's next login.

Comment: passwd -e changes the login shell.

Comment: `passwd -e` works for me (Linux Mint 17.3)

Comment: `passwd -e` works in RHEL 7.0

Comment: @schily The options for `passwd` vary per distribution.  On RHEL, `-e` forces a password change on next login.

Comment: @jrw32982 it is unfortunate, that the Linux people create options to programs that are in conflict with long existing ones from UNIX. The option -f to expire the password is more than 30 years old already and predates Linux by many years. Even the option -e to change the login shell predates a complete Linux.

Comment: @jrw32982supportsMonica you're most probably right. On the other hand I can't understand how the UNIX guys could name `-f` an option to **e**xpire the password and `-e` to change the **s**hell instead of the obvious `-e` and `-s` respectively. Viewed from here and now, such decision looks like it was asking for trouble.