# Can I make it so that all new users created in the future will have an expired password by default?

Tags: password, useradd

I want to make it so that every time anyone creates a new user on my system that user will be forced to set a password during their first login. I can't find anything in `/etc/login.defs` that will do it. I also tried to find something in `/etc/pam.d` and was unsuccessful. Essentially I want any new user to have an expired password without needing someone to `chage -d 0` or `passwd -e`.

Is there a parameter for `useradd` that I can set the password age to expired so that I could make an alias or a wrapper for `useradd`? Or would I have to make an alias for `useradd` with `chage -d 0` after it?

I'm not a sys admin, we ship RHEL with our product and I've been tasked to change our default security settings. Any useful suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/173708/how-do-i-force-a-user-to-change-a-password-at-the-first-time-login-using-ssh

Comment: The difference between that and this is that I want to not just set one user's password expired, I want to ensure that if a new user is created in the future the user will be forced to change the password immediately. It's not a question of now, but how do I make an expired password the default for all new users?

Comment: You could write a wrapper around `adduser`/`useradd` and `passwd`/`chage` to do this for you.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the indicated question.

Comment: Correct @BenAveling. But sometimes you just can't get everyone to read the questions accurately.  
It turned out we block useradd for non-root users and have a shell for customers to add new users. Adding chage -1 to that script was trivial. If only they had told me about that script before I posted!

Answer (score 2):

You can to do it using `passwd`'s `-e` option after creating the account. `useradd` has `-e` option for expiring a user account, not password.

From `man passwd`:

> -e, --expire
>
> Immediately expire an account's password. This in effect can force a user to change his/her password at the user's next login.

Comment: That affects an existing account, which is not what the question is about.

Comment: @Gilles Edited, I hope it's clear now.